# What can I do in W10 to ensure that the results of a .bat file go to the correct directory?

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat file that contains gam commands that download a number of .csv files to my C \GAMWORK directory working in w11.

However, the same .bat file only sends the same .csv's to my downloads folder working in my work computer running w10. No idea why...

Here are some screen shots, first, W11 THEN W10[![enter image description here][1]][1]:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

many thanks!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJE2A.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvLpd.png

Comment: Please replace your screenshots with actual text posted within code boxes. That means we need to see the content of the batch file and the Command Prompt output in a format that we can all copy and run, to reproduce your reported issue.

Answer (score 2):

In the screenshot you posted the path to the BAT file seems incorrect:

```
C:\1>C\GAMWORK\getKaminParsbyGrd.bat
```

try running it like this:

```
C:\GAMWORK\getKaminParsbyGrd.bat
```